# convert database description string to html code in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am creating a laravel web application for a client which allows them to store information into a database.

So i am using a WYSIWYG editor to allow the users to enter data with bullet points, bold text and underlines ect...

Now when i save the description to my database it looks like this.

```
test test&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;egergererh&lt;i&gt;this is a bullet&lt;/i&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;i&gt;hello&lt;/i&gt;egerg&lt;/u&gt;ewg&lt;/b&gt;ewg&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;wegwe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;ewg&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

So when the user previews the page with the description i want it to show with the html marked up. But instead I find a string of html that looks like this on my page.(not the real thing for an example)

```
test test <div><br/><div></div></div>
```

How do i retrieve the description from the database and present it to the page as html?

i have tried

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

but this doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it with:

```
<?php
$str = 'test test&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;egergererh&lt;i&gt;this is a bullet&lt;/i&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;i&gt;hello&lt;/i&gt;egerg&lt;/u&gt;ewg&lt;/b&gt;ewg&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;wegwe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;ewg&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';

echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Comment: Better yet, decode before its written to the database.

Comment: Sorry it does, it was actually laravel blade template that wasnt working with this. Once i changed from {{ html_entity_decode($product['description']) }} to <?= html_entity_decode($product['description']) ?> it worked fine ! :)